# What is the Backbone way to modify models when added to collection?

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js, collections

My models have an `index` attribute which defaults to `null` but should be set by the collection, when added to it. This is what I first thought of, but didn't work.

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        index: null,
        // ...
    },
    // ...
});

var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // ...
    add: function(model) {
        model.set({ index: this.size() });
        return model;
    },
    comparator: function(model) {
        return model.get('index');
    },
    // ...
});
```

However, this doesn't work. It throws the error `TypeError: model.set is not a function`. What is the correct way or what options do I have?

Comment: Leaving a comment since it doesn't answer your question, but ideally your models wouldn't have that `index` property at all. By adding it, you are creating the need to synchronize the order of the models in the collection with the `index` attribute on the model. But there is no need to have that information stored in two places. Why not just query the collection for the model's index when you need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not really override the `add` method for this.

[The documentation states](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add) that an `add` event is fired on the collection whenever a model is added to it. You can listen to this event and do whatever you need to do.

In the [event catalog](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) you can see that the `add` event handler will receive the added model as the first parameter, so you could do something like:

```
var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('add', function (model) {
            model.set({ index: this.size() });
        }, this);
    },
    //...
});
```

If you also want to run this on models passed to the constructor, do something like this:

```
var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(models) {
        _(models).each(function (model, i) {
            model.set({ index: i });
        });

        this.on('add', function (model) {
            model.set({ index: this.size() });
        }, this);
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought that was correct, but unfortunately, the callback doesn't get executed when a model is added.

Comment: @danijar Bad news, I will test it :).

Comment: @danijar It seems to work [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XkgLu/), please take a look and I think we will find out what is wrong.

Comment: It seems that, when passing models right through the collection constructor, Backbone adds them first, and calls `initialize()` afterwards. This has already bothered me once before. Do you know how to make it work with the constructor? http://jsfiddle.net/XkgLu/1/

Comment: When `initialize` is called, those models are not yet added into the collection. But you receive them as the first parameter of `initialize`. You could do [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/XkgLu/2/).

Comment: This isn't explicitly wrong if you only ever use `.add(model)`, but note that using `size()` like this will will set the wrong index if the collection has a comparator, you`add` at a specific index, or use `unshift`.